# Get year from day number counter

Tags: date

I have an integer that shows the number of days since Jan 1, 1970, where for instance 1969-12-31=-1, 1970-01-01=0, 1970-01-02=1, and so on. I would like to know an algorithm that will take this day number and tell me in which year the day is. So for instance days 0 to 364 lie in year 1970, days 365 to 729 lie in year 1971, and so on. Keep in mind that the algorithm must accept both positive and negative numbers; however, it does not need to deal with the Julian to Gregorian calendar changeover (i.e. we can assume that the current Gregorian calendar system stretches backward continuously in time).

Comment: @sasfrog - I will need to ultimately do this in Java but an answer in any language is acceptable, as I should be able to adapt the logic to Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. Here is some Java code that works.

```
public int yearFromDays(int days) {
    double d0 = days + 719162;
    double n400 = Math.floor(d0/146097.0);
    double d1 = d0 % 146097;
    double n100 = Math.floor(d1/36524.0);
    double d2 = d1 % 36524;
    double n4 = Math.floor(d2/1461.0);
    double d3 = d2 % 1461;
    double n1 = Math.floor(d3/365.0);
    double year = 400*n400 + 100*n100 + 4*n4 + n1;
    if (n100 != 4 && n1 != 4) year++;

    return (int)year;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend against using doubles here.  Because every intermediate value you produce will be an integer, you can simply use an int, or a long if you are concerned about overflow.  Remember, integer division will automatically round down.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with the Java API:

```
public int yearFromDays(int days) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(new Date(0));
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, days);
    return c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```